# How would I divide a string contained in one cell into several?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel 2010 sheet with a column containing information that I'd like separated into several columns as follows: -

A1="Height 17cm Width 6cm Depth 6cm"

turn in to...

B1="Height 17cm"
C1="Width 6cm"
D1="Depth 6cm"

The words appear in each cell but the numerical values will be different.

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you try Text to Columns with a fixed Width?

Comment: @ScottCraner Fixed width Text to Columns won't work if 17cm changes to 171cm.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald it sure will if the data is coming in with tabs instead of spaces, not enough info to judge, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are spaces put this in B1 and copy over and down

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*198+1,198))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Scott :-) If I wanted to perform this function on Column F and have the resulting columns be O,P,Q what modification would I need?

Comment: Change just the `$A1` to your reference in F and put the formula in O and drag across.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either a find replace to replace cm by cm% (or any other extra special character) and do a Text to Columns specifying your new character as the delimiter, or use formulas in cells B1 through D1.

Formula in B1 would be `=LEFT(A1,FIND("cm",A1)+1)`

Formula in C1 would be `=MID($A1,LEN(B1)+1,FIND("cm",MID($A1,LEN(B1)+1,50))+1)`

in D1 `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1&C1))`

Regular expressions would be faster but more complex initially.